# In WPF (.net 4.0), how to make a child window block the code while not block the main window?

Tags: wpf, modal-dialog, window, async-await

I have a WPF application to running test cases and collect results. On the main window, use can select some test cases and run them circularly. When running a case, a custom child window will popup and show user some data, then user click button "**Pass**" or "**Fail**" to set the result of this test case and close this child window. Then next test case starts running. On the main window, there is a "**Stop**" button. And user can click it to stop the loop testing after current round is finished.
The code is like:

```
while (!stopByUser)
{
   foreach(var caseItem in caseList)
   {
      // on TestWindow UI, caseItem.isPassed will be set by user with clicking buttons;
      caseItem.isPassed = false;
      TestWindow tw = new TestWindow(caseItem);
      tw.ShowDialog();
      if (caseItem.isPassed)
      {
         totalPassed++;
         // update UI ...
      }
   }
}
```

The problem is user cannot click the "Stop" button on the main window since I use tw.ShowDialog() to popup a modal window. However, I also cannot simply change it to tw.Show() to popup a non-modal window since the code in the foreach loop must be executed synchronously.

And I found the native MessageBox have this ability: **block the code while not block the main window**. eg.

```
var result= MessageBox.Show(message, "Is this test case passed?", MessageBoxButton.YesNo);
// the following line will be executed after the MessageBox is closed
// and meanwhile I can operate my main window when the MessageBox is still visible
var passed = (judgement == MessageBoxResult.Yes);
```

So my question is **how can I achieve this ability by using WPF Window in .net 4.0?**
My application will be run on windows xp, so .net 4.0 is mandatory.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your design requirements might be questionable, but it if you want to stick with it, you still have some options: 1) use a separate UI thread for the message box, 2) use p/invoke and call the native `MessageBox` API, 3) Use `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` and `async/await` to keep you `foreach` loop while still using modeless `Window.Show/Close` as @VMaleev suggests.

Answer (score 0):

MessageBox.Show blocks all windows because it uses ShowDialog method. What you could do is to write logic:

1. Give next item
2. Create new window for it
3. Subscribe Closed event of this window
4. OnClosed event update your ui and go to step one

Example:

```
    private bool stopByUser {get;set;}
    private int currentItemIndex {get;set;}
    private List<object> caseList {get;set;}]
    private TestWindow tw {get;set;
    public void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ShowNext();
    }

    private void ShowNext()
    {
        if (stopByUser) return;

        var caseItem = caseList[currentItemIndex++]
        caseItem.isPassed = false;

        tw = new TestWindow(caseItem);
        tw.Closed += (s, e) => 
        { 
            if (caseItem.isPassed)
            {
                totalPassed++;
                // update UI ...

                ShowNext();
            }
        };
        tw.Show();
    }
```

Comment: MessageBox.Show() seems do not block the main window. I can still interact with the main window. eg. click the "Stop" button

Comment: I cannot. You could share sample project where this behavior is. Meanwhile, I suggested real workaround for your question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Noseratio and @VMaleev's help, I finally end up with a solution by using Microsoft.Bcl.Async and async/await. It's not beautiful, but it works.

```
while (!stopByUser)
{
   foreach(var caseItem in caseList)
   {
        caseItem.isPassed = false;
        GlobalVar.isFinished = false; // static variable: isFinished
        TestWindow tw = new TestWindow(caseItem);
        tw.Closed += (s, e) =>
        {
            GlobalVar.isFinished  = true;
        };
        Task task = new Task(() =>
        {
            while (!GlobalVar.isFinished)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        });
        task.Start();
        tw.Show();
        await task;
        // get the test result here from GlobalVar.isPassed
        var passed = caseItem.isPassed;
        // do other things
   }
}
```

And remember that to use Microsoft.Bcl.Async, .NET Framework 4.0 (with **KB2468871**) must be installed on xp/win7. See more [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2012/10/22/using-async-await-without-net-framework-4-5.aspx)

Comment: You should be using `TaskCompletionSource` instead of `Task` here.